# UILabel text overrun in custom tableCell

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a weird problem in a custom UITableCell subClass.This custom cell has a pair of UILables that are multi-line and can contain varying amounts of text (up to 2000 characters). The custom tableCell has a layout method where I am calculating their frame's height using the code below, taking the device orientation into account:

```
if (isPortrait) {
    presentationTextLabelSize = [presentationTextStr sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(portraitDescriptionWidth, 2000.0f) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    presentationTextLabelRect = CGRectMake(60.0f, 25.0f, portraitDescriptionWidth, presentationTextLabelSize.height);
} else {
    presentationTextLabelSize = [presentationTextStr sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(landscapeDescriptionWidth, 2000.0f) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    presentationTextLabelRect = CGRectMake(60.0f, 25.0f, landscapeDescriptionWidth, presentationTextLabelSize.height);
}

self.presentationTextLabel.frame = presentationTextLabelRect;
```

I have the label's autoResizeMask set as follows:

```
self.presentationTextLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

I use the same calculation in the UITableViewController to set the row height.

Everything works perfectly, the label is sized to the correct height for it's width, and the cell autoResizes on device rotation, except that when the device is rotated to landscape the label's text sometimes extends out of the label's frame to the right, clear past the edge of the tableView. If I scroll the cell out of view and back again it's back to normal. I am logging the cell's width to the console, and it is correct, yet the text extends far past that width.

Any ideas what's joing on?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly this has to do with caching of the `UITableViewCell` instances in the table. There may well be a better solution; but could you send the `UITableView` a `reloadData` message on device rotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, the `tableView` is not reloaded when the device is rotated to landscape. So, there is mismatch in updating the texts. Use `[tableView reloadData];` at the place, where you find the device is changed to landscape mode.

Comment: This answer put me on the right track, although it was more complex than just reloading the table data. I had to do do custom relayout in the custom tableViewCell for all the visible cells, and also changed the way I was setting the custom cells textField width. I ended up useing the bounds of the contentView to accurately set the textField width.